# Second scanf is not working

Tags: c

i am having trouble with this c language code:

```
 char st[2];

 printf("enter first value:");
 scanf("%c", &st[0]);

 printf("enter second value:");
 scanf("%c", &st[1]);
```

So my computer didn't ask me to enter the second value, I mean to say that it only print the first `printf` statement then I enter a character and then it only prints the second `printf` statement and program end without taking the second input.

Please help.  What's wrong with this code?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c

Comment: It must be the day for `scanf` questions. [Same problem as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016073/scanf-fails-why), I think. []()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well it did. The character(s) produced by the ENTER key is present in the buffer already.

Answer (score 9):

use `fflush(stdin);` function before the second `scanf();`. It will flush the ENTER key generated after first scanf();.
Actually, your second scanf() is taking the ENTER as its input and since scanf terminates after getting an ENTER, it is not taking anything else by your side.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is the second scanf is receiving the "Enter" key press.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the implicit newline you entered as the second character, i.e. `st[1]` is getting the value `'\n'`. An easy way to fix this is to include the newline in the expected format string: `scanf("%c\n", &st[0]);`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &st[0]);
```

to this

```
scanf(" %c", &st[0]);
```

That's a shotty answer (no error checking or anything) but its quick and easy.