# While-loop ignores scanf the second time

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char loop='y';
    while(loop != 'n') {
        printf("loop? ");
        scanf("%c", &loop);
        if(loop != 'y') {
            loop='n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I type in 'y' he restart the while-loop but ignores the scanf the second time and end the loop after that. Can anyone help?

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Second scanf is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023643/second-scanf-is-not-working)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scanf skips every other while loop in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669821/scanf-skips-every-other-while-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure the `scanf` discards the newline. Change it to:

```
scanf(" %c", &loop);
       ^
```

Comment: @user1069968 That space makes `scanf` ignore all whitespace (including newlines).

Answer (score 11):

You probably had to enter a newline so the input goes to your program, right? The second time your loop executes it reads that newline character, which was "waiting" to be read and automatically exits the loop (`'\n' != 'y'`). You can make scanf ignore whitespace by using this format string instead:

```
" %c"
```

Comment: This is the best explained answer on this thread. Thank you for saving my girlfriends homework! <3

Comment: Thanks @AustinWitherow , I’m happy to know it was useful to you :)

Answer (score -2):

One solution can be the use `fflush(stdin)` after the `scanf()` statement to clear the input buffer.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior in C programming. It might work as intended on some systems, but it is not good practice in general.

Comment: @NisseEngström Thanks Nisse, I agree with with your point. It's not a good practice as we can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122550/fflushstdin-function-does-not-work

Comment: fflush stdin also work on linux but avoid use it its UB, by using it you lost portability.