# C - Hashtable Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: c, hashtable

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define m 9



int flag1=1;
//Creating memory for username and password
struct node // The list that is being used to store username and password
{
    char username[30];
    char password[30];
    struct node *next;
};

int getkey(char[30]); //a method to get "randomly" a key
int hash(int);  // a method to create the hashcode
void insert(struct node **,char[30],char[30]); //adding a node struct to a specific possition in hashtable
void initializeHashTable(struct node **);
void search(struct node **,char[30]);//check if password exists
void searchuser(struct node **,char[30]); //check if username exists
void print(struct node**);//printing the hashtable

void print(struct node **T)
{
     struct node *tmp;
     int i,flag=0;
     printf("-------Data Base-------\n");
     for(i=0;i<m;i++)
     {
         tmp=*(T+i);
         while(tmp!=NULL)
         {
             printf("Username: %s  Password: %s\n",tmp->username,tmp->password);
             tmp=tmp->next;
         }

     }
}
void search(struct node **T,char password[30])
{
    struct node *tmp;
    int i,flag=0;
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        tmp=*(T+i);
        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tmp->password,password)==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }
        if(flag==1)
            break;

    }
    if(flag==1)
         printf("Authentication Successfull\n");
    else
       printf("Authentication Failed\n");

}

void searchuser(struct node **T,char user[30])
{
    struct node *tmp;
    int i,flag=0;
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        tmp=*(T+i);
        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(tmp->username,user)==0)
            {
                flag=1;
                break;
            }
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }
        if(flag==1)
            break;

    }
    if(flag==0)
      {
           printf("Username NOT Found\n");
           flag1=0;

      }
}

void initializeHashTable(struct node **T)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<m; i++)
        *(T+i)=NULL;

}
int getkey(char name[30])
{


    int i=0;
    int key=0;
    for (i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        key+=name[i];

    }
    return key;

}

int hash(int key)
{
    return key%m;
}

void insert (struct node **T,char name[30],char password[30])
{

    struct node *newnode;
    newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strcpy(newnode->username,name);
    strcpy(newnode->password,password);
    int key;
    key=getkey(name);
    int hashcode;
    hashcode=hash(key);
    //printf("Key:%d\n",key);
   // printf("Hashcode:%d\n",hashcode);

    if(*T+hashcode==NULL)
    {
        (*(T+hashcode))->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=NULL;
    }
    else
    {

        newnode->next=(*(T+hashcode));
        (*(T+hashcode))=newnode;
    }



}



int main()
{//possible content of file: phill 1234
    char choice;
    struct node **T;
    struct node **head;
    head==NULL;
    T=(struct node**)malloc(m*sizeof(struct node));//creating the hashmap
    FILE *fp;
    char name[30];
    char pass[30];

    fp=fopen("passwords.txt","r");

    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File Not Found");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        initializeHashTable(&(*T));
        while(!feof(fp)) // end of file
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%s %s",name,pass); //reads until first wild space,
            //one each loop, you get 1 username and 1 password from the file
            //adding them on hashmap
            insert(&(*T),name,pass);


        }
    }

    //user authentication
    do{

        printf("Enter Username:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&name);
        searchuser(&(*T),name);
        if(flag1==1)
        {
        printf("Enter Password:\n");
        scanf("%s",&pass);
        search(&(*T),pass);

        }
        printf("Try Again? (y/n)\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }while(choice!='y');

    free(T);
    free(fp);
    free(head);



    }
```

---

- My code  works fine on the loop , it does the authentication
  successfully but then sometimes it crashes, or i give the same
  details(username and password) and somehow the authentication fails
- part of the code that i believe its buggy:

  ```
      //user authentication
      do{
      printf("Enter Username:\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%s",&name);
      searchuser(&(*T),name);
      if(flag1==1)
      {
      printf("Enter Password:\n");
      scanf("%s",&pass);
      search(&(*T),pass);

      }
      printf("Try Again? (y/n)\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      scanf("%d",&choice);
  }while(choice!='y');
  ```

  if i put `do..while(choice=='y')` which means run the loop `while choice=='y'`it stops `if choice=='y'` which is kinda odd

> Issue: Authenticator doesn't work properly after 1st try

Thanks A Lot For Your Time!

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger to trace the execution of your program and to examine its state. That's the best way to debug such issues (can't always turn to SO to debug for you).

Comment: i've tried for weeks, didn't find a solution...how can i use a debugger?

Comment: Try to use fgets() instead of scanf().  On the last scanf(), there is a good possibility that a unwanted newline char that got carried over.  Insert this line `fgets( stdin, garbage, sizeof(garbage))` after the last scanf(). and  declare `char garbage[50];`.

Comment: fgets() its for file i believe

Comment: Google "how to use a debugger". You'll save yourself alot of time if you stop what you are coding now and invest in learning to use a debugger. That's an essential tool.

Comment: i get "too few arguements to function fgets()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues that jump out at me:

```
struct node **T;
...
T=(struct node**)malloc(m*sizeof(struct node));
```

Do you intend for `T` to be a sequence of `struct node` (in which case the type of `T` is wrong), or a sequence of *pointers* to `struct node` (in which case, the argument to `sizeof` is wrong)?

It would be a lot cleaner (and much less error-prone) if you wrote

```
T = malloc( m * sizeof *T );
```

then it's just a matter of deciding the type of `T`.  Personally, I would expect you to be allocating a sequence of `struct node`, so that would likely be declared

```
struct node *T = malloc(  m * sizeof *T );
```

However, the rest of your code really seems to assume that `T` is a sequence of pointers to `struct node`, so in that case that would be

```
struct node **T = malloc( m * sizeof *T );
```

That's the beauty of this idiom - the only thing you need to change is the type of `T`.  The `malloc` call itself doesn't need to change.  If the type of `T` is `struct node *`, then `sizeof *T` is equivalent to `sizeof (struct node)`.  If `T` is `struct node **`, then `sizeof *T` is equivalent to `sizeof (struct node *)`.

Then there's this:

```
initializeHashTable(&(*T));
```

which should really just be

```
intializeHashTable( T );
```

Also,

```
while(!feof(fp))
```

is always wrong - `feof` won't return true until *after* you attempt to read past the end of the file, so you'll wind up looping once too often.  You should check against the result of the input operation instead:

```
while ( fscanf(fp,"%s %s",name,pass) == 2 )
{
   insert(T,name,pass);
}
```

Again, the argument `&(*T)` should just be `T`.

As for your input:

```
printf("Enter Username:\n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",&name);
```

<strike>The `fflush` call is unnecessary here - if there's an input operation immediately following an output operation, a flush is implied.</strike>

**Edit**

I'm embarrased to say that I misread that `fflush` call - for some reason I read that as `fflush( stdout)`, meaning you'd want to make sure your output was written to the console before calling `scanf`.

Calling `fflush` on an input stream is erroneous, and the behavior on doing so is *undefined*.  It won't clear the input stream of any unread input (except in MSVC, and that's because Microsoft decided to codify existing bad behavior).

Lose the `fflush` call altogether.

**End edit**

The `scanf` call should be

```
scanf( "%s", name );
```

The `&` is unnecessary here - `name` will implicitly be converted from type "30-element array of `char`" to "pointer to `char`".  Same for `pass`.

**Edit**

As written, these `scanf` calls are unsafe - if you type in a string that's longer than the target buffer, `scanf` will happily write those extra characters to the memory immediate following that buffer, resulting in anything from corrupted data to a seg fault.  You need to make sure you don't read too many characters.  You can do that either with a field width specifier, such as

```
scanf( "%29s", name );  // leave at least one element for the 0 terminator
```

or use `fgets`:

```
fgets( name, sizeof name, stdin );
```

The `fgets` call will read and store the trailing newline to the buffer if there's room, so you'll need to do some extra work:

```
char *newline = strchr( name, '\n' );
if ( *newline )
  *newline = 0;
```

If there's no newline in the buffer, then you will want to clear the input stream before the next read:

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' )
  ; // empty loop
```

**End edit**

```
  scanf("%d",&choice);
}while(choice!='y');
```

You're using the wrong format specifier to read `choice` - you're telling `scanf` to expect a decimal integer input, not a character.  `'y'` doesn't match up with the format, so `scanf` doesn't actually read it from the input stream, and `choice` is not updated.  You should change that to

```
  choice = getchar();
} while ( choice != 'y' );
```

There are plenty of other issues, but start with those.

Comment: The `fflush` call there is indeed *unnecessary* because [**it's erroneous**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122550/fflushstdin-function-does-not-work)! People often (*erroneously*) use <strike>`fflush(stdin)`</strike> to bring the cursor for `stdin` to the next newline (i.e. to discard it, because otherwise `name` would be read as a blank field); they should be using something like `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` instead.

Comment: @Seb: derp.  For some reason I was reading that as `fflush( stdout );` - I'll fix that part of my answer.

Comment: Good. I particularly love that you use the optimistic loop (expecting the return value to be 2, rather than incorrectly expecting it to be inequal to `EOF` as I so often see). I still have a few small problems with this. Firstly, `scanf( "%29s", name );` does something subtly different to `fgets( name, sizeof name, stdin );` as they use different sets of delimiters. You could replace the `strchr` advice that follows (which dereferences `NULL` when no newline is found) with `strcspn` advice (which wouldn't).

Comment: ... `while ( getchar() != '\n' );` might loop infinitely; it'd be safer as `scanf("%*[^\n]"); getchar();` to correctly break when `EOF` occurs. Speaking of handling `EOF` correctly, `getchar` returns `int`: either an error corresponding to a negative value (`EOF` denoting a read error or end-of-file, as opposed to a character value) or a positive value (an `unsigned char` denoting a character value as opposed to an error). By downward-converting you lose the error handling information. `choice` should be `int` and `while ( choice != 'y' );` should be `while ( choice != 'y' && choice != EOF );`