# do-while loop in C not working

Tags: c, do-while

I'm new to C so I'm sorry if it's a really silly mistake, but I can't seem to figure out why my code isn't working. All it should do is take in input from the user until the user inputs either "y" or "n". However, the loop doesn't break when I input "y" or "n" (or anything else!).

```
do{
    printf("Would you like a daily newspaper (y/n): "
    scanf("%c",&news);       //get newspaper preference
    news= tolower(news);
    fflush(stdin);
}while((news !=  'y') || (news != 'n'));
```

I tried running the bits of code individually, and it seems to be working then. Not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is Undefined behavior

Comment: At least one of the two conditions in the OR clause will always be true. You probably want an AND here.

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&news); ` otherwise `\n` will be consumed by the next `scanf()` call

Comment: This `((news !=  'y') || (news != 'n'))` is the same as `!((news ==  'y') && (news == 'n'));` (for details see [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Comment: thank you all the code is now working!

Comment: `(news !=  'y') || (news != 'n')` is always true. They cannot be both false on the same time (that could happen only when `news` is simultaneously `'y'` and `'n'`, which is impossible). The condition you need is `(news !=  'y') && (news != 'n')`.

Comment: If you still have `fflush(stdin);` and your program is running, you are / might be in trouble.

Comment: @babon what do you mean?

Comment: Read this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122550/fflushstdin-function-does-not-work and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior