# C: For loop acting REALLY strangely with scanf

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, scanf

So I've got the following code:

```
int q, x, y;
char l;
for (q = 0; q<10; q+=1) {
    printf("%d\n", q);
    if (3 == scanf("%c %d %d", &l, &x, &y)) {
        printf("%d\n", q);
    }
}
```

I would expect this to run "scanf" 10 times. Each time it will print 'q' before I enter anything, and once again after. So the expected output should be this (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
0
> a 1 1
0
1
> b 2 2
1
2
> c 3 3
2
...and so on.
```

But I actually get this.

```
0
> a 1 1
1
1
2
> a 2 2
3
3
4
> a 3 3
5
5
6
> a 4 4
7
7
8
> a 5 5
9
9
```

If I take out the scanf function, it counts from 0-9 as expected. What's happening with the scanf function to make the for loop act so weirdly? I've got some experience in Java/Python, but I'm totally new to C.

Editing the code based on your comments to this (apologies for weird formatting):

```
for (q = 0; q<10; q+=1) {
        printf("%d: ", q);
        if (3 == scanf("%c %d %d ", &c, &x, &y)) printf("%d\n", q);
        else { printf("WTF %d\n", q); }
    }
```

half solves the problem. It works for all of the iterations EXCEPT for the first one. As so:

```
0: a 0 0
WTF 0
1: b 1 1
1
2: c 2 2
2
```

What's going on there? There is other outputted code above that first line, from another part of the program. Could that be causing this?

Comment: Getting input should always be done through fgets+sscanf to avoid such and other common mistakes and vulnerabilities.

Comment: This is for a uni assignment and we have to use scanf unfortunately.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While-loop ignores scanf the second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300963/while-loop-ignores-scanf-the-second-time). Try to search this site before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `%s`, `%d`, `%f`, and most other conversion specifiers, the `%c` conversion specifier doesn't skip over any leading whitespace, so it's picking up the newline from the previous entry.

After you type `a 1 1 <Enter>`, the contents of the input stream are `{'a', '1', '1', '\n'}`.  The first `scanf` consumes the `a`, `1`, and `1`, leaving the trailing `\n` in the input stream.  `scanf` returns 3 and you print the value of `q`.

The second time through the loop, `scanf` picks up the leftover `\n` and assigns it to `l`, but since there's nothing else in the input stream it doesn't assign `x` or `y`, so it returns a value of 1 and your branch isn't taken.  Then the loop starts over again.

The easiest way around this problem is to put a leading space in the format string before the `%c` conversion specifier:

```
if (3 == scanf(" %c %d %d", &l, &x, &y))
  printf("%d\n", q);
```

That leading space in the format will cause `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace in the input stream, so you won't accidentally pick up the trailing newline from the previous entry.  Of course, if you *want* to pick up any whitespace characters, you'll have to do something different.

Answer (score 4):

you have unconsumed "\n", getchar() will consume it:

```
if (3 == scanf("%c %d %d", &l, &x, &y)) {
    getchar();
    printf("%d\n", q);
}
```

Comment: or just: if (3 == scanf("%c %d %d\n", &l, &x, &y)) printf("%d\n", q);

Comment: or just: if(3 == scanf("%c %d %d ", &l, &x, &y)) to remove any whitespace stuff.

Comment: I have used this method, but it still is giving an error on the first iteration. I've added details to the OP cos I can't format in comments. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try adding an else statement and printf to your vars to debug this?
It seems that for every time (3 == ..) is true, there is another time that it is false.
scanf might be running twice for the newline character when you hit enter...

Answer (score 0):

scanf function is returning different values instead of 3(three inputs). I don't know exact reason but I feel because of spaces in scanf("%c space %d",&c,&i); function it is returning different values.