# Do while loop won't run in a program to only take upper case letter from user

Tags: c, loops, input

```
> #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;
    printf("Enter a capital alphabet: ");
    do{
    scanf("%c", &a); }
    while(a>=65 && a<=90);
}
```

I am building a program which only takes one uppercase letter as input. But it doesn't prompt to input again, even if I input a lowercase letter, a number, or a symbol.

Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: `while(a>=65 && a<=90);` is "read again if input is ASCII uppercase letters".

Comment: It shows process returned.

Comment: Your prompt is outside of the loop so it will only ask the once.

Comment: Is using `isupper()` from `ctype.h` allowed?

Comment: @FreudianSlip  even without the printf, it doesn't show the prompt for input. It executes and closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;  
    do{
        printf("Enter a capital alphabet: "); // printf should be in while loop to print the request when you did not enter a capital alphabet.
        scanf(" %c", &a);  // add space character before %c

    } while(a <='A' || a >= 'Z'); // it's more clear when you use 'A' and 'Z' in stead of 65 and 90.
}
```

See [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

and [While-loop ignores scanf the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300963/while-loop-ignores-scanf-the-second-time)

Answer (score 2):

- Add a whitespace character before `%c` to have it skip newline character (from hitting Enter)
- Negate the loop condition to read again if the input is out of desired range.
- Use character literals for better understanding.
- Use `isupper()` for even better understanding.

Manual comparision version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;
    printf("Enter a capital alphabet: ");
    do{
    scanf(" %c", &a); }
    while(!(a>='A' && a<='Z'));
}
```

`isupper()` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a;
    printf("Enter a capital alphabet: ");
    do{
    scanf(" %c", &a); }
    while(!isupper((unsigned char)a)); /* case to unsigned char to avoid trouble when a is negative */
}
```

Comment: ...and add `\n` to `printf` so it will flush the output.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie But it will add extra newline to the output. Using `fflush(stdout);` should be better for flushing the output without affecting the contents.