# Not asking for char "choose" Before switch statement

Tags: c, char

This code executes itself without asking for char "choose" for further processing before the switch statement `scanf("%c",&choose); switch(choose)`.

```
printf("enter option 1,2,3 or 4 \n\n");
scanf("%c",&choose); // why it not ask to input char
switch(choose)
{
    case '1': case '+':
    {
        printf("enter 1st value\n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("enter 2st value\n");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        c=a+b;
        printf("%f + %f = %f",a,b,c);
        break;
    }
    case '2': case '-':
    {
        printf("enter 1st value\n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("enter 2nd value\n");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        c=a-b;
        printf("%f - %f = %f",a,b,c);
        break;
    }
    case '3': case'*':
    {
        printf("enter 1st value\n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        printf("enter 2nd value\n");
        scanf("%f",&b);
        c=a*b;
        printf("%f * %f = %f",a,b,c);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Have you declare `choose` anywhere? 2. What do you mean by why does it not ask - do you mean there is no text there?

Comment: Is there anything else BEFORE this printf/scanf? For example...[another scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023643/second-scanf-is-not-working)?

Comment: I've declared char choose but it is not working with switch if change variable char to int choose; then it will work but it will no longer able to store arithmetic signs like +-*

Comment: int main()
{
    int Caltype;
    char choose;
    float a,c,b;

    printf("Hello, \n Choose type of calculator!\n");
    printf("1. normal \t 2. scientific\n");
    scanf("%d",&Caltype);
    if(Caltype==1)
    {
    printf("what do you want to do:");
    printf("\n\n    1.\" + \"   2.\" - \"   \n\n    3.\" * \"    4.\" / \"   \n\n");
    printf("enter option 1,2,3 or 4 \n\n");
    scanf("%c",&choose);
       switch(choose)

Comment: Follow link in my comment (same - common - problem), ENTER character isn't removed by previous scanf from input buffer. It's also what unwind said in his answer.

Comment: try `scanf(" %c", &choose);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("enter option 1,2,3 or 4 \n\n");
scanf("%c",&choose);
```

In your code if you are using any `scanf` before the above given code, then this behaviour is expected as the previous `scanf` reads the input leaving `\n` in the input buffer which is feeded as input to next `scanf`.

To overcome this issue please use `fflush(stream)` before `scanf(...)`, this should solve the problem.

```
 fflush(stdin);
```

or you can use `getchar()` function, this will alse solve your the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you've already input something earlier, so that there are non-scanned characters left in the buffer which this "greedy" `scanf()` then scans without stopping.

You should check the return value of `scanf()` to learn if it succeeded or not.

And you should switch to using `fgets()` to read in a whole line, and then parse that. It's much safer and easier to predict, that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've executed it without any problems (it gets the "choose" char):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv ) {
        char choose;
        float a,b,c;
        printf("enter option 1,2,3 or 4 \n\n");
        scanf("%c",&choose); // why it not ask to input char
           switch(choose)
        {
            case '1': case '+':
                {
                            printf("enter 1st value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&a);
                            printf("enter 2st value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&b);
                            c=a+b;
                            printf("%f + %f = %f",a,b,c);
                            break;
                }
            case '2': case '-':
                {
                            printf("enter 1st value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&a);
                            printf("enter 2nd value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&b);
                            c=a-b;
                            printf("%f - %f = %f",a,b,c);
                            break;
                }
            case '3': case'*':
                {
                            printf("enter 1st value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&a);
                            printf("enter 2nd value\n");
                            scanf("%f",&b);
                            c=a*b;
                            printf("%f * %f = %f",a,b,c);
                            break;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Probably its something you didn't read before...

I'm guessing that you are doing a similar "scanf("%c",&choose);" before, so the next read you will get the carriage return.

You could try to change the following lines:

```
scanf("%c",&choose);
```

for:

```
scanf("%c%*c",&choose);
```

...so you discard the \n

If this don't solve your issue, maybe you should provide more code :)

Comment: `scanf("%c%*c",&choose);` no effect. change to `scanf(" %c",&choose);`