# Infinite loop when assigning a float to an integer

Tags: c

Please i'm having an issue with my program. Whenever i try to input a float it's getting into an infinity loop. I know that the input is stored as an integer. How can prevent the user from entering a float (how to filter the input).

Why is the program getting into an infinite loop when the input is a float.

This is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i<10){
        system("cls>null");
        printf("%d^2 = %d\n", i, i*i);

        printf("Index: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the manual for `scanf`. Make sure you handle *every* way in which it can behave.

Comment: get the input as a string, parse it to int and check if it could be parsed or not.

Comment: That's what i mean. how can i do that?

Comment: Why the program doesn't ask anymore for an entry when a float is assigned?

Comment: because scanf continues to fail.

Comment: .. Where in that code is `float` mentioned?

Comment: @EdHeal Incorrect input is.,

Comment: When i try to input a number like '4.5' the program never ask for an input and goes into an infinity loop? how scanf works exactly? I'm not familiar with buffer.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016073/scanf-fails-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `scanf` to read a number, but the input contains something incompatible with the input format specifier, `scanf` does not consume such incorrect input, leaving it in the buffer. Your program does not clear the buffer on input mismatch, entering an infinite loop: `scanf` tries to read an `int` again, sees that it's not there, and exits without modifying `i`. Your loop sees that `i` is less than 10, and calls the `scanf` again.

To fix this, check that `scanf` returned one input. Use the input when it is correct, or call `scanf` again with the `%*[^\n]\n` specifier, which means "read to the end of the string, and discard the input":

```
if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) {
    scanf("%*[^\n]\n");
}
```

Note the asterisk - it means that the consumed input needs to be discarded, rather than being written into a variable.

Comment: How does it get the input when it read it to the end? is it works like the casting?

Comment: The `[^\n]` format means "string consisting of any characters except newline, repeated any number of times". Asterisk tells `scanf` to discard that string. `\n` at the end removes the `\n` from the buffer. So `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` call removes the current line from the input buffer, without even looking at its content. By the way, inside that `if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1)` is a good place to add a `printf` telling the user that the input is not valid, and that he should please enter another integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Better use `fgets()` to read a complete line from stdin, and `strtol()`
to parse it into an number, for example:

```
char buffer[256];
char *endp;
int i;
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
    // buffer now contains one line (including the terminating newline)
    i = (int)strtol(buffer, &endp, 10);
    // endp points to the first character after the parsed number:
    if (endp > buffer && (*endp == 0 || isspace(*endp))) {
        printf("%d^2 = %d\n", i, i*i);
    } else {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    float j = 0;
    while(i<10)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("%d^2 = %d\n", i, i*i);

        printf("Index: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &j) <= 0 && j-fabs(j) != 0)
        {
             printf ("The input is not an interger");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dasblinkenligh Well... I think read the input as a string, check whether all are digits, and then use `sprintf()`.will solve the problem. Right?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia You should use the return value of `scanf`. i.e. should return 1

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia Yes, that's one way to fix it. Another one is checking the return value of `scanf`, as pointed by Ed.